# Speed difference between Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below two tables:

1.cases : No. of columns in table - 330.
        No. of records in table - 57981

2.accounts : No. of columns in table - 115.
             No. of records in table - 2422858

Now to select records from both table I wrote below two queries:

1.

```
    select a.full_name,c.name from 
    cases c left join accounts a on c.account_id=a.id
    where c.date_entered between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-18' and c.deleted=0
```

This query gives me results in **1 Min 6 Sec**

2.

```
    select a.full_name,c.name from 
    cases c,accounts a
    where c.account_id=a.id and c.date_entered between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-18' and c.deleted=0
```

This query gives me results in **1 Sec**

Can anybody tell me why there is huge speed difference?
Is second query good to go?
Is there any third way to optimize my query?

Note: There is index added on account_id column of accounts table.

Comment: I think the second query might be going via an inner join, but you should just check the query execution plan to see what is going on.  My guess is something will stand out.

Comment: Since these queries return different results, you can not really compare them in speed

Comment: Both queries return the same number of rows?

Comment: You are comparing two different queries, one an outer join and one an inner join.  It should not be a surprise that they have different execution plans, just as two meals with different ingredients have different nutritional values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query yields an **explicit `outer join`**, which certainly requires a full table scan, regardless the index.

The second one yields an **implicit `inner join`**, which, by the way, most certainly will make use of the index for key lookup or even a hash join.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for your reply. Should I use second query?

Comment: @Mak_091 Use query with appropriate join. If you need INNER JOIN then setup it in the first query. If you really need left join then your second query is wrong and you need to change it

Comment: @Mak_091, I agree with @Livius. We can't tell you whichever INNER or OUTER is right. To the given task you must state which is more appropiate. One  shall ask: Ok, there's a relation between `cases` and `accounts`. The query shall yield, for any not deleted `case`, its `name`. Then, for any such `case` there shall be a related `account` or there may be `case`s with no related `account`? This question lends to either an INNER or an OUTER join.

Comment: Please, @Mak_091, take note! It's better you make use of explicit join sintax as SQL92's standard. Hence, if you choose the second **approach**, make sure you use the most appropriate **syntax**: `from cases c inner join accounts a on a.id = c.account_id`

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN

```
select a.full_name,c.name from 
    cases c left join accounts a on c.account_id=a.id
    where c.date_entered between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-18' and c.deleted=0
```

INNER JOIN

```
 select a.full_name,c.name from 
    cases c,accounts a
    where **c.account_id=a.id** and c.date_entered between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-18' and c.deleted=0
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer.  And the syntax used in the second query is archaic and should not be used.

Comment: this you so want, until ms will not prohibit the use of any code is correct